# How does the glm() function in R treat a date variable?

Tags: r, date, logistic-regression

I'm including a date variable in a logit model using glm(). My aim is to have fixed effects based on date, meaning that the model will control for each date. The variable inputted into the function is a date class. Does glm() treat a date class variable like fixed effects? It is not clear to me, because the model doesn't show a coefficient for each date as I would expect. If not, I will transform the date to a factor class.

Comment: A date is a numeric variable - `unclass(Sys.Date())` - so it will be treated like any other number by `glm`. `glm(x ~ y, data=data.frame(x=1:10,y=Sys.Date()+0:9))` I suspect you want to make it a factor if you want it as groups with coefficients.

Comment: Relevant discussions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65900/does-it-make-sense-to-use-a-date-variable-in-a-regression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date is a numeric variable

```
unclass(Sys.Date())
#[1] 17297
```

...so it will be treated like any other number by `glm()`.

```
coef(glm(x ~ y, data=data.frame(x=1:4,y=Sys.Date()+0:3)))
#(Intercept)           y 
#     -17296           1
```

I suspect you want to make it a `factor()` if you want it as groups with coefficients.

```
coef(glm(x ~ y, data=data.frame(x=1:4,y=factor(Sys.Date()+0:3))))
#(Intercept) y2017-05-12 y2017-05-13 y2017-05-14 
#          1           1           2           3
```